# I am extremely new to python and I am making a random number guessing game

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, numbers

For right now, I have it so it will print the random number it chose. However, whether I get it wrong or right it always says I am wrong.

here is my code:

```
import random

amount_right = 0
number = random.randint(1, 2)
guess = input
print(number)

print(
    "welcome to this number guessing game!! I am going to think of a number from 1-10 and you have to guess it! Good luck!")

input("enter your guess here! ")

if guess != number:
    print("Not quite!")
    amount_right -= 1
    print("you have a score of ", amount_right)

else:
    print("good Job!!")
    amount_right += 1
    print("you have a score of ",amount_right,"!")
```

what did I do wrong? I am using Pycharm if that helps with anything.

I tried checking my indentation, I tried switching which lines were the if and else statements (lines 13 - 21) and, I tried changing lines 18 - 21 to elif: statements

Comment: `guess = input` does not ask for any input but assigns the input function to guess which is not what you want.

Comment: input is in wrong line, you have to take input and store it directly

Comment: You want `guess = int(input("enter your guess here! "))`

Answer (score 1):

```
guess = int(input())
```

You need to convert your guess to `int` and there should be `()` in input

Also there are 2 `input()` in your code. One is unnecessary. This can be the code.

```
import random

amount_right = 0
number = random.randint(1, 2)
print(number)

print(
    "welcome to this number guessing game!! I am going to think of a number from 1-10 and you have to guess it! Good luck!")

guess = int(input("enter your guess here! "))

if guess != number:
    print("Not quite!")
    amount_right -= 1
    print("you have a score of ", amount_right)

else:
    print("good Job!!")
    amount_right += 1
    print("you have a score of ",amount_right,"!")
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions "that have been asked and answered many times before".